# Objc code cannot find Bool variable defined in swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have a var defined in one Swift file, but in another Objective-C file, when I try to set this var, the complier complains it cannot find the var. How do I solve this problem? here is the code:
in swift:

```
var isCreating: Bool!
```

in objc :

```
SelectMemberViewController *ctrl = [[SelectMemberViewController alloc]init];
ctrl.isCreating = YES
```

then the complier is complaining : Property 'isCreating' not found on object of type 'SelectMemberViewController'

Comment: Is it in a framework?  Have you tested with other functions on the class?  If it is in a framework, you will need to declare it as public.

Comment: Too vague. Show the actual declaration in Swift, the actual call in the Objective-C file, and the actual compiler message.

Comment: @chrisco I never declare any "public" type of thing, it seems vars or vals in swift class are default accessible as long as you are holding the object, am I right?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The problem is that nothing in Objective-C's world corresponds to a `Bool!`. Thus, this declaration is not exposed to Objective-C. You need to declare this a plain `Bool` if you want Objective-C to be able to see it.

Comment: Yes, it solves the problem, thanks, is it because Bool in objc is a primitive, so it does not correspond to any optional type?

Comment: Yes. Or from Swift's terminology, it is not an AnyObject and only an AnyObject can be nil in ObjectiveC (an id).

Comment: var isCreating: Bool = false. Initial first time is fix it.